# Python: summarizing data from list using index from another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
L1 = ['A','B','A','C','A']
L2 = [1,   4,  6,  1,  3]
```

I want to create a dictionary which has the following output:

```
DictOutSum = {'A':10, 'B':4, 'C':1}
DictOutCount = {'A':3, 'B':1, 'C':1}
```

i.e. Lists L1 and L2 both have same number of elements and the elements in them corresponds one to one. I want to find sum of all numbers in L2 for each unique element in L1 and make a dictionary out of it(DictOutSum). I also want to create another dictionary which stores the counts of number of unique elements of L1(DictOutCount).

I don't even have an idea where to start for this other than to use a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure python implementation:

```
>>> dict_sum = dict.fromkeys(L1, 0)
>>> dict_count = dict.fromkeys(L1, 0)
>>> for k,n in zip(L1, L2):
...    dict_sum[k] += n
...    dict_count[k] += 1
...     
>>> dict_sum
{'A': 10, 'B': 4, 'C': 1}
>>> dict_count
{'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}
```

Fancy one-liner implementations:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(L1)  # dict_count
Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 1})
>>> sum((Counter({k:v}) for k,v in zip(L1, L2)), Counter())  # dict_sum
Counter({'A': 10, 'B': 4, 'C': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function

```
import collections

DictOutSum = collections.defaultdict(int)
DictOutCount = collections.defaultdict(int)

for l1, l2 in zip(L1, L2):
    DictOutSum[l1] += l2
    DictOutCount[l1] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> L1 = ['A','B','A','C','A']
>>> L2 = [1,   4,  6,  1,  3]
>>>
>>> DictOutCount = {v:0 for v in L1}
>>> DictOutSum = {v:0 for v in L1}
>>> for v1,v2 in zip(L1,L2):
...   DictOutCount[v1] += 1
...   DictOutSum[v1] += v2
...
>>>
>>> DictOutCount
{'A': 3, 'C': 1, 'B': 1}
>>> DictOutSum
{'A': 10, 'C': 1, 'B': 4}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The mega elementary way

```
L1 = ['A','B','A','C','A']
L2 = [1,   4,  6,  1,  3]

# Carries the information
myDict = {}

# Build the dictionary
for x in range(0,len(L1)):

    # Initialize the dictionary IF the key doesn't exist
    if L1[x] not in myDict:
        myDict[L1[x]] = {}
        myDict[L1[x]]['sum'] = 0
        myDict[L1[x]]['count'] = 0

    # Collect the information you need
    myDict[L1[x]][x] = L2[x]
    myDict[L1[x]]['sum'] += L2[x]
    myDict[L1[x]]['count'] += 1

# Build the other two dictionaries
DictOutSum = {}
DictOutCount = {}

# Literally feed the data
for element in myDict:
    DictOutSum[element] = myDict[element]['sum']
    DictOutCount[element] = myDict[element]['count']

print DictOutSum
# {'A': 10, 'C': 1, 'B': 4}

print DictOutCount
# {'A': 3, 'C': 1, 'B': 1}
```

Side note: From your username, are you Persian?

Comment: lol .. no I am American .. Zanam .. "Z is my name" which Idk how it became Zanam. But what is Zanam then in Persian?

Comment: @Zanam Literally, it means "I'm a woman". "Zan" means woman. "Am" is additive to the noun to say that it describes you. So, "Zanam" means "I'm a woman".

Comment: I should change my name to Jenny or something, people will be waiting to respond to my questions

Answer (score 0):

**DictOutCount**, use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter),

```
import collections
DictOutCount = collections.Counter(L1)

print(DictOutCount)
Counter({'A': 3, 'C': 1, 'B': 1})
```

---

**DictOutSum**,

```
DictOutSum = dict()
for k, v in zip(L1, L2):
    DictOutSum[k] = DictOutSum.get(k, 0) + v

print(DictOutSum)
# Output
{'A': 10, 'C': 1, 'B': 4}
```

---

Previous answer, DictOutSum,

```
import itertools
import operator
import functools

DictOutSum  = dict()
for name, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(itertools.izip(L1, L2)), operator.itemgetter(0)):
    DictOutSum[name] = functools.reduce(operator.add, map(operator.itemgetter(1), group))

print(DictOutSum)
{'A': 10, 'C': 1, 'B': 4}
```

The main steps are:

- use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=izip#itertools.izip) to make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of `L1` and `L2`
- use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) to make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable (sorting before that)
- use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) for cumulatively addition